# Equivatlent to 3dsMax’s “Expose Transform”?

Tags: tracking, drivers

Is there any possible way to get access to an object's rotation, in its parent's space, to use in a driver when it is being driven by a constraint like "Track To"?
In 3dsMax I would have been able to achieve this with an object called Expose Transform that will reveal an object's Position/Rotation/Scale relative to the origin space of another object as if the other object was its parent, even if there is no kind of connection.
There may be many instances where I could use a similar feature. I wonder if there is anything like this.

Comment: I'd rather use a *Copy Rotation* constraint and avoid using drivers in this case. If you could give a precise example of what you're trying to achieve regarding the different spaces, we could give you a complete answer.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! This will work for the particular case I had in mind. It's likely I will still run into situations where I would want an expose Tm, but this will do nicely in this particular case. Luckily copy rotation has an option for "Local Space". (I have two objects that are both children of a parent empty. The first object is tracking a target. I need the other object to mimic the rotation of the first object, but relative to its parent, which may have its own orientation)